# How to add compileOnly dependency on bootRun plugin

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a spring-boot project managed by gradle. And below is a runtime dependency for my project:

```
compileOnly group: 'org.apache.drill.exec', name: 'drill-jdbc-all', version: DrillJDBCVersion
```

Gradle uses this dependency during compile process. I want to provide it during the runtime. It works fine but I don't know how to make it work with `gradle bootRun`. It is very useful for development environment.

How can I add this dependency on `gradle bootRun`?